# Tone down the grey for formatting code/commands?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13077/is-profile-sourced-by-bash/13182#13182) is really brutal on the eyes however I think it's key to have filenames and commands with that kind of formatting.

Maybe perhaps toning it down a bit? Similar in shade to the blockquote perhaps? Example:

`ouchy ouch commands hurt eyes`

> softer nicey nicey commands not so much.

Note: I am only talking about the background grey color, we should (for obvious reasons) keep the monospaced font for the code and commands.

Answer (score 6):

On StackOverflow, the background color for code is the same as for block quotes. The only difference between the two is that code font is monospace.

I think that would work great here too.

[image]

Comment: +1 for StackOverflow style

Answer (score 1):

I have put in a fix, it will be in the next deployment. I have lightened the code from #ccc to #e0e0e0 (still slightly darker than the blockquote).

Comment: In a code block we now have two colors: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16610/white-screen-with-pointer-after-removing-unity/16617#16617

Comment: the fix is on the way.

Comment: Woohoo, you did it! :-)